# The right function or method when creating applications, software, web and other software?

Tags: php, android, algorithm, documentation, crud

I am a beginner learning programming, I have learned about variables, data types and so on.

But why isn't it as easy as making an application, software that I imagine? I was confused when reading the programming documentation

And when do we need a method or function from php programming documentation or java, android or other programming language documentation?

Do we have to guess for the method of programming documentation needed to create applications, software, web?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to learn by heart all those functions, only some of them which you will use most of the time. It is more important to learn concepts, programming paradigms, patterns and other things.

Of course, any language has it's power, so there are some sections you should study.
Not knowing what a language supports is like reinventing the well already implemented in that language.

For example, POO implementation. Some languages allows an object to extend multiple parents (e.g: C++). Other languages will force you to extend only one parent (e.g: Java, PHP); this has and advantage because in Java and PHP there is no diamond problem to solve (check wikipedia for more details)

The better you understand POO the better your design after a model will be.

If you learn about arrays in PHP, and you are asked to implement a sort, look for sort functions in documentation. Before making you own function, search if there is already created one. It is easy to find functions related to data type and objects.

Hope it helps